# PowerQuery Date formats with leading blanks

Tags: excel, powerquery

The log file that I have to use as a data source contains a date section in the form:

```
Fri Jun 30 19:50:10 2023
```

For some bizarre reason the logging software adds a leading zero to times (19:50 / 09:50 etc) but doesn't do the same for dates (30 Jun /  1 Jul) instead, it adds a leading space.
This breaks my new custom column based on:

```
DateTime.FromText([tDateTime],[Format="ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Culture="en-US"])
```

I've tried the obvious (single 'd' rather than double and including a leading space all of which result in an error as soon as I hit 1 Jul  I've not been able to find anything here or via Prof. Google

Comment: You could `Text.Split` on the `space`; Remove the blank `""` list items; Recombine the elements in the proper order. The `Datetime.FromText` function will then recognize the result.

Answer (score 2):

In case no one picks this up and posts a more elegant solution...
After a fair bit of trial and error, I found a workaround:

```
DateTime.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.Range([Column1],0,24),"  "," "),[Format="ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", Culture="en-US"])
```

This replaces the double space with a single one allowing the format to work.